# Equivalent for Oracle Enterprise Management Console for Mac

Tags: macos, oracle-enterprise-manager

Somebody can advise an equivalent for Enterprise Management Console? I found this 
Oracle Enterprise Manager 10g Grid Control Management Agent. But i cant launch it. There is two jar file. I try to run it, but it doesn't work.

dhcp-176:~ kukodajanos$ java -jar /Users/kukodajanos/Downloads/macosx_10_1_0_3_agent_download/macosx/agent/stage/install1.jar 
Invalid or corrupt jarfile /Users/kukodajanos/Downloads/macosx_10_1_0_3_agent_download/macosx/agent/stage/install1.jar

I checked the manifest, and there is no main-class specified. Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you trying to monitor a database that runs on an OSX machine? Or to view OEM data from an OSX machine? Agent is for monitoring databases. Console is for viewing monitoring information from a client. Clarify and then maybe we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: No no, the database runs on an external server. And i have an MacBook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install
"Oracle Database 10g Client Release 2 (10.2.0.4.0) for MAC OS X on Intel x86 / x86-64", which contains the Java Enterprise Manager Client (if your Mac is have Intel CPU).

But Java based Enterprise Managment Console as included in Client installer is obsolete for 10G. To control the 10G and 11G use Enterprise Manager through the web.

Comment: Through Web? There is no appropriate Desktop application for Mac? I feel like uncomfortable Web based monitoring.

Comment: There is only one fully functional application from Oracle. Others are very limited in their ability, and only for Windows.